# How to get powershell runspace status in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I'm working with Powershell runspaces in ASP.Net MVC and finding it difficult to get documentation on how to check the status of an existing Powershell Runspace.
Really appreciate any insight!

Controller

```
public class DemoController : ApiController
{
    PowerShell psInstance = PowerShell.Create();
    static Runspace rSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

...

private void Initialise()
    {
        try
        {
            psInstance.Runspace = rSpace;
            if (HOW TO CHECK IF RUNSPACE IS ALREADY OPEN?) <<-- 
            {
                DO NOTHING
            }
                else 
            {
                rSpace.Open();
                LoadModules();
            }
        }
        catch (CmdletInvocationException e)
        {
            rSpace.Close();
            rSpace.Dispose();
            psInstance.Dispose();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you not find the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.runspacestateinfo(v=vs.85).aspx) for it? Also, why not create a static/class constructor and just `Open` it once there?

Comment: Good point....I might just do that!

Answer (score 3):

Inspect the [`RunspaceStateInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.runspacestateinfo(v=vs.85).aspx) property

```
if(rSpace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened)
{
    // runspace is open, do stuff
}
else if(rSpace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.BeforeOpen)
{
    // call rSpace.Open() before invocation
}
else 
{
    // runspace state is either broken, already in use or closed
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Worked a treat, thank you!